# Why is it that potential difference decreases in thermistor when temperature of circuit is increased?

Tags: electric-circuits, temperature, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electronics

Why is it that potential difference decreases in [thermistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) when temperature of circuit is increased? From my understanding when temperature increases, there are more free electrons ($n$) so according to $I=navq$, current increases as $n$ is greater. But why is it that potential difference decreases; if $V=IR$ shouldn't pd also increase?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing cause and effect.  The current is a function of the applied voltage, or the other way around.  It is incorrect to say that a thermistor changes in voltage or current as a function of temperature.  That's dependent on the circuit it is connected to.

The external property that changes in thermistors as a function of temperature is the resistance.  R goes up or down with increased temperature, depending on the kind of thermistor you have.  Most things just called a "thermistor" exhibit decreased resistance with rising temperature.  There are also such things as PTC (positive temperature coefficient) thermistors that exhibit the opposite effect.

As you say, V = IR.  If R goes down, the V will go down at the same I.  Conversely, if V is held constant, the I goes up.  Both can be legitimate ways to run a thermistor.  Probably the most common way is to put the thermistor in series with a fixed voltage and a fixed resistance.  In that case, both I and V go down as R goes down.

Answer (score -2):

if the temperature decreases the resistance of the thermistor will increase so the potential different will increase because V=IR so if R is increased then the total answer for V will increase

Comment: The resistance of a thermistor goes down with temperature, so this is incorrect.